# Partial Elimination of Matrix in Linear System

Tags: matlab

I am wondering what is the most efficient way in matlab to eliminate (in the sense of linear system solve) some rows of a matrix. Basically, given rows "s" and "l" (such that s and l are distinct and their union is 1:n), how to efficiently compute

A is large n x n sparse SPD matrix.

```
R = chol(A(s,s))
Atemp = R' \ A(s,l)
All = A(l,l) - Atemp' * Atemp
```

Basically I am computing the trailing matrix of a partial Gaussian elimination.
The code above, for large and sparse A, spend almost all his time in the second and particularly third line. Any hint on how to improve this ?
The size of s is typically 10% of the size of l.

Thanks a lot